# List<MyStructure> error: App crashes, No idea why

Tags: java, android, list, class

I've built some class named "item", here is it: (thats the whole code)

```
public class item {
private int id;
private String title;
private String desc;
private double lat;
private double lon;
private String pub;
private int p;
private int n;

public item(int id, String title, String desc, double lat, double lon, String pub, int p, int n) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.desc = desc;
    this.lat = lat;
    this.lon = lon;
    this.pub = pub;
    this.p = p;
    this.n = n;
}
```

Now I have to make a `List<item>` and `add()` "item"s to it, but for some reason my application crushes.

Thats the Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    List<item> markers;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        item a = new item(1, "lol", "sdfs", 32.45345, 34.54353, "nir", 0, 0);
        markers.add(a);


    }
```

LOGCAT:

```
08-10 16:32:46.710: D/AndroidRuntime(2934): Shutting down VM
08-10 16:32:46.710: W/dalvikvm(2934): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41a0a930)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testitems/com.example.testitems.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at com.example.testitems.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:18)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
08-10 16:32:46.777: E/AndroidRuntime(2934):     ... 11 more
```

Appreciate your help guys!

Comment: Are you getting an error message? What does it say?

Comment: Initialıze your markers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize your markers list

```
List<item> markers=new ArrayList<item>();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<item> markers;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     markers = new ArrayList<item>();

    item a = new item(1, "lol", "sdfs", 32.45345, 34.54353, "nir", 0, 0);
    markers.add(a);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the list before you use it.

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<item> markers = new ArrayList<item>();
    item a = new item(1, "lol", "sdfs", 32.45345, 34.54353, "nir", 0, 0);
    markers.add(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any object should be **initialized before using** its methods, however you seem to forgot this step before adding data in your list. Initialize `markers` before adding data in it.

```
 List<item> markers=new ArrayList<item>();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have not initialize the arraylist object to remove these errors
see the following steps mention below:

1. First allocate memory to the Arraylist object like this

   public class MainActivity extends Activity {

   ArrayList markers;

   @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   ```
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          markers = new ArrayList<item>();

          item a = new item(1, "lol", "sdfs", 32.45345, 34.54353, "nir", 0, 0);
          markers.add(a);
   ```

}

1. Secondly to handle the error use the try and the catch block .

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList markers;

@Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       try
       {

```
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           markers = new ArrayList<item>();

           item a = new item(1, "lol", "sdfs", 32.45345, 34.54353, "nir", 0, 0);
           markers.add(a);

    }
    catch(Exception e) 
    {
         //Write to android ddms logger.
            or
          make a Toast Message
    }
```

}

1. Free the resources which has been intialize like arraylist etc. 
    By putting   finally block after the catch Block.